# Grails + sqlite

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, grails, groovy

Is there any way to use SQLite as a database storage for my Grails app?

If I use a SQLite JDBC driver (http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/), my app fails to start with "Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [SQLite]"

The only workaround I found was http://d.hatena.ne.jp/torutk/20090711/p3 (it's in Japanese, have it [google translated](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A//d.hatena.ne.jp/torutk/20090711/p3&hl=en&langpair=auto|en&tbb=1&ie=EUC-JP) if you want), but it does not make any help.

Or, is the idea of using SQLite for web apps so terrible that nobody uses it?:)

EDIT: Yes, I know, the default Grails HSQLDB support works just fine, but my web app is a part of a bigger system which uses solely SQLite, so we would prefer end up supporting only one database instead of both HSQLDB and SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it but you might want to try using the SQLiteDialect from the [hibernate-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-sqlite/) project.  They even show you a sample connection String in [their readme.txt](http://hibernate-sqlite.googlecode.com/files/readme.txt)

There are some [comments in this thread](http://noor.ojuba.org/2008/07/groovy-with-sqlite/) that might help you gain some context.

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom dialect. For SQLite it should be simple.

Refer [Hibernate SqLiteDialect](http://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/blob/73d07f0990ecfd9b9a869066b8f7b3e023af39ff/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a file based db, grails comes with built in access to [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), which can be easily configured to be in-memory or file based.  I was initially going to try to use sqlite, but went with HSQLDB approach because of grail's default support for it, and I have not run into any problems so far.

Comment: Sadly, other part of our application uses SQLite, so we would prefer using SQLite over HSQL to avoid supporting two databases at once