# How to conect a Sqlite datasource in grails 3.3.9 in intellij J 2021

Tags: sqlite, intellij-idea, grails, groovy, datasource

i need some help: i try to connect sqlite datasource from a file in grails 3.3.9

This is my applicatiom.yml file:

```
hibernate:
   cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: false
    use_query_cache: false
dataSource:
     pooled: true
     jmxExport: true
     driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
     username: sa
     password: ''
dataSources:
   IkebanaUser:
    dbCreate: "update"
    url: "jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser"
    logSql: "true"
    dialect: "SQLiteDialect"
    driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
environments:
   development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: create-drop
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

   test:
        dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
production:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
        url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        properties:
            jmxEnabled: true
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 50
            minIdle: 5
            maxIdle: 25
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
            defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    dataSources:
            IkebanaUser:
                dbCreate: "update"
                url: "jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser"
                logSql: "true"
                dialect: "SQLiteDialect"
                driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
```

and this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       mavenLocal()
       maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
 dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.15.1"
}
```

}

```
version "0.1"
group "ikebana.gammaversion"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"

repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
```

}

```
dependencies {
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
   compile "org.grails:grails-core"
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
   compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
   compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
   compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
   compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
   compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n"
   compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
   compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
   compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:async"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:events"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
   compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.16.Final"
   compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
   console "org.grails:grails-console"
   profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
   runtime "org.glassfish.web:el-impl:2.1.2-b03"
   runtime "com.h2database:h2"
   runtime "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc"
   runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.15.1"

   runtime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.6.17'

  testCompile "org.grails:grails-gorm-testing-support"
  testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
  testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"
  testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
  testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
```

}

```
bootRun {
   jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
   addResources = true
   String springProfilesActive = 'spring.profiles.active'
   systemProperty springProfilesActive, System.getProperty(springProfilesActive)
```

}

```
assets {
     minifyJs = true
     minifyCss = true
```

}

this mis my domain class
class Usuario {

```
  static constraints = {
 }
static mapping = {
    datasource 'IkebanaUser'
}
private def nombre
private def apellido

def getNombre() {
    return nombre
}
```

......

and my "controller" is

```
class UsuarioController {
  static scaffold= Usuario
   def index() { }
}
```

i see too this post [Grails and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691940/grails-and-sqlite) to create a SQlitedialect.java  in a java directory(see the image)  , mi S.O is Ubuntu 18.04, y think that the error is in my aplciation.yml.Help please.. thanks a lot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5sxI.png)

And the error is this

Running application...
2021-07-02 22:59:01.614 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1072)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
at ikebana.gammaversion.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:928)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:805)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:573)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:432)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:206)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1265)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1099)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:276)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(HibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:86)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:39)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.connections.AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractHibernateConnectionSourceFactory.java:23)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.create(AbstractConnectionSourceFactory.java:64)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.InMemoryConnectionSources.(InMemoryConnectionSources.groovy:26)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.connections.ConnectionSourcesInitializer.create(ConnectionSourcesInitializer.groovy:28)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.(HibernateDatastore.java:201)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1076)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
... 77 common frames omitted

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error |
  Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Need in the build.graddle:

```
         compile group: 'com.zsoltfabok', name: 'sqlite-dialect', version: '1.0'
```

and trash this line too

```
runtime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.6.17'
```

and .yml look that

dataSource:

```
 pooled: true
 jmxExport: true
 driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
 username: sa
 password: ''

 dataSources:
     IkebanaUser:
        pooled: true
        driverClassName: "org.sqlite.JDBC"
        username: ''
        password: ''

environments:
    development:
       dataSource:
       dbCreate: create-drop
       url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

       dataSources:
           IkebanaUser:
           url: jdbc:sqlite:/home/marcos/IkebanaUser
           dbCreate: update
  test:
      dataSource:
           dbCreate: update
           url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

  production:
     dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
        url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000; DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        properties:
        jmxEnabled: true
        initialSize: 5
        maxActive: 50
        minIdle: 5
        maxIdle: 25
        maxWait: 10000
        maxAge: 600000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        validationQuery: SELECT 1
        validationQueryTimeout: 3
        validationInterval: 15000
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
        defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```